# How do I replace a string-value in a specific column using method chaining?

Tags: python, pandas, method-chaining

I have a pandas data frame, where some string values are "NA". I want to replace these values in a specific column (i.e. the 'strCol' in the example below) using method chaining.

How do I do this? (I googled quite a bit without success even though this should be easy?! ...)

Here is a minimal example:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3,4],
                   'B':['val1','val2','NA','val3']})
df = (
    df
    .rename(columns={'A':'intCol', 'B':'strCol'})  # method chain example operation 1
    .astype({'intCol':float})  # method chain example operation 2
    # .where(df['strCol']=='NA', pd.NA) # how to replace the sting 'NA' here? this does not work ...
    )
df
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try replace instead of where:

```
df.replace({'strCol':{'NA':pd.NA}})
```

Comment: This is the one-liner I was looking for, because it also acts only on the column of interest ...

Answer (score 0):

Use `lambda` in `where` clause to evaluate the chained dataframe:

```
df = (df.rename(columns={'A':'intCol', 'B':'strCol'})
        .astype({'intCol':float})
        .where(lambda x: x['strCol']=='NA', pd.NA))
```

Output:

```
>>> df
   intCol strCol
0     NaN   <NA>
1     NaN   <NA>
2     3.0     NA
3     NaN   <NA>
```

Many methods like `where`, `mask`, `groupby`, `apply` can take a callable or a function so you can pass a lambda function.

Answer (score 0):

[`pandas.DataFrame.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) does

> Replace values where the condition is False.

So you need condition to **not** hold where you want to make replacement, simple example

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]})
df2 = df.where(df.x%2==0,-1)
print(df2)
```

gives output

```
   x
0 -1
1  2
2 -1
3  4
4 -1
5  6
6 -1
7  8
8 -1
```

Observe that *odd* values were replaced by `-1`s, whilst condition does hold for *even* values.